# Trigger recognising data as duplicates when it isn't

Tags: sql-server, triggers, duplicates, inner-join, rollback

I have this trigger in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON [dbo].[practiseduplicates]   
AFTER INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM [practiseduplicates] t 
               INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.[money] = t.[money] 
                                     AND i.[Name] = t.[Name] 
                                     AND i.[year month] = t.[year month])
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RAISERROR ('Duplicated Data', 16, 1);
    END
```

I then insert these values (which are already in the data table):

```
insert into [practiseduplicates]
values ('2017-02', 'buzzlightyear', '10.09')
```

When I click execute I expected the error message to pop up... which it did, however when I change the values to information that I know is not in the data table

e.g.

```
'2056-12', 'mr potato head', '12345.09'
```

The error message still pops up, when in actual fact it should have just inserted the data into the table, does anyone know why this is the case?

I suspect its to do with my inner join statement but I am not sure.

Comment: I hope this is a learning about triggers excercise, because keeping duplicates out is the job of unique constraint.

Comment: well it's more keeping duplicates out, than a trigger exercise. So i'm guessing i'm now using the wrong technique?

Comment: Yes, wrong technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I used a constraint to solve this rather than a trigger statement.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[practiseduplicates]    
ADD CONSTRAINT [constraintforduplicates] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
( [column name],
[column name], etc etc
)
```

This stops any duplicates using the columns you state in the constraint statement as the data to compare to and flag if they're duplicates and doesn't insert the data into the table.

Note that the columns in the statement have 900 byte constraint themselves. So e.g if you had varchar (max) column, the constraint would not run as the maximum it can do is 900 bytes. In my script I put varchar (800).

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from your question

> When I click execute I expected the error message to pop up... which it did, *however when I change the values to information that I know is not in the data table*

That italic part of the statement is not quite accurate, because even if those values were not in the table before, after you run insert, they are in there. And the trigger will fire.

In short, you are creating an **AFTER INSERT** trigger and check if the data inserted to the table is already in the table (**after the insert is ran**). Of course the trigger will fire every time because if the data is in the inserted table, it is in the table (because it was just inserted).

Comment: I see, so what would be the right technique for this, Shannon above suggested a unique constraint?

Comment: Based on what you posted, yes, it seems that unique constraint on those 3 columns would do what you want on that table (provided that there has not been any duplicate so far).